# How to solve headers already sent by error in sqladmin.php on line 636

Tags: php, warnings

I need small help on how to solve this error that I receive after I submit data. data submit successfully but I see this error every time i do submit data "Below"

```
Array
(
    [0] => ../upload/tmp/eb56163c635cf89918baa7ed93b9adee_3.jpg
    [1] => ../upload/tmp/eb56163c635cf89918baa7ed93b9adee_3.jpg.jpg
    [2] => 91
    [3] => 76
    [4] => 92
    [5] => 140
    [6] => 91
    [7] => 76
)
Array
(
    [image] => Resource id #203
    [type] => 2
    [width] => 500
    [height] => 450
)

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite/admin/lib/debug.php:25) in /home/mysite/admin/lib/sqladmin.php on line 636
```

**/home/mysite/admin/lib/debug.php** file below:

```
<?php


// dependencies


/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function PrintR($array , $die = false) {
    echo "<table><tr><td><pre style=\"background-color:white\">";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre></td></tr></table>";

    if ($die)
        die();
}


/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function Debug($array , $die = false) {
    if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] != "127.0.0.1") {
//      return "";
    }

    PrintR($array , $die);
}




?>
```

To make it easier: /home/mysite/admin/lib/sqladmin.php on line 636

```
header("Location:" . $this->templates["generic_form"]->blocks["Temp"]->Replace(array_merge($_GET,$_POST)));
                            exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The header function expects nothing to be outputted before it is ran. By printing the arrays like you did or echoing an error from the debug.php file (which seems to be the case here), that means the output is being written, and this will create a conflict for the header. Try removing it.